# Why after validation of post title, when I have got validation error, browser passes to Rails server the previous value of post title?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, routes

I get posts by :title instead :id

routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
#RSS
get 'feed' => 'posts#feed'
get 'archive' => 'posts#archive'
  devise_for :users, controllers: { omniauth_callbacks: "callbacks" }
  root to: "posts#index"

  resources :posts, param: :title do
    resources :comments, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]

    resources  :images do
      resources :comments, only: [:new, :create]
    end

    resources  :links do
      resources :comments, only: [:new, :create]
    end
    resources :photos, only: [:new, :create,:destroy]
    resources :songs, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
  end
```

post_controller:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:new, :create, :show]
  respond_to :html, :json, :rss, :atom
  def index
    if params[:search].blank?
      @posts = Post.includes(:comments, :photos).all
    else
      @search = Post.search do
        fulltext params[:search]
      end
      @posts = @search.results
    end
    respond_with(@posts)
  end

  def show
    set_post
  end

  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

  def edit
    @post = Post.find_by(title: params[:title])
  end

  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    @post.errors.add(:base, :invalid) unless @post.save
    respond_with(@post)
  end

  def update
    set_post # this @post dont get post becouse browser pass wrong title and rails dont find it
    if @post.valid? # here error becouse @post hasnt find
        @post.update(post_params)
    else
      @post.errors.add(:base, :invalid)
    end
     respond_with(@post)
  end

  def destroy
    set_post
    @post.destroy
    respond_with(@post)
  end

  def feed
    @posts = Post.all.reverse
    respond_with(@posts)
  end

  def archive
    @posts_by_year = Post.limit(300).all.order("created_at DESC").
    group_by {|post| post.created_at.beginning_of_year}
  end

  private

  def set_post
    #fix N+1 queries and find by posts title
    @post = Post.includes(:comments, :photos, :links).find_by(title: params[:title])
  end


  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :content)
  end
end
```

When I create new post, if I include in my post title a dot, I get from Rails error. Therefore I use  validation format: method for this case.

post.rb:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  #overwrite the to_param for changing routes from posts/id to posts/title
  def to_param
    title
  end

  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy, as: :commentable
  has_many :images,   dependent: :destroy
  has_many :links,    dependent: :destroy
  has_many :photos,   dependent: :destroy
  has_many :songs,    dependent: :destroy

  validates :content, presence: true
  validates :title, presence: true, length: { maximum: 100 }
  validates :title, format: { without: /\./,
                              message: "must be without dot" }

  searchable do
    text :title, :content
  end
end
```

After this, when I **update** the post,my validation format method works and I get my validation message 'must be without dot'. Well. I delete in my post title input field dots and submit form. **Now browser send to server previous post title value with dot.**

```
Started PATCH "/posts/my%20test%20post%20title%20with%20dot." for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-01-26 11:57:34 +0300

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [PATCH] "/posts/my%20test%20post%20title%20with%20dot."):
```

Therefore rails can't find post by title with dot an I get the error.
**What can I solve this problem? Maybe :title instead :id in this case is bad idea?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're using `form_for`?  Rails will set the title on the post object then run validation.  When it fails it will display the edit view, `form_for` will then use the `to_param` method to set the url, which will use the posts updated title.  When you try and update again it'll use the title from the url to try and find the post, but won't be able to because there isn't a post in the database with that title.

You should use something like [friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) but if you really want to roll your own then a simple implementation would be to have a slug column which gets set based on the title `after_validation` but obviously you're going to have to make sure it's unique so personally I'd switch to friendly id or another gem that deals with slugs.